# What is redeemable about Aidan?

Tags: being-human-us

After watching most of the episodes or reading reviews on i09 I find myself wondering how is it that Aidan is supposed to be a good person? He is constantly having relapses. He rarely seems repentant about any of the horrible things he's done other than getting a little mopey. In the first season he killed a coworker killed, his neighbors son (ok he was a vampire at the time but he killed him in such an awful way and it turned out for something that wasn't the kids fault), had flash back to when he killed a wedding party and turned Bishop from falling in love and trying to live a life like Aidan is trying to live now. Decided to save Heggemann instead of a pregnant lady carrying twins and in the second season hasn't done anything different really. Plus he's actually stealing life saving blood from the hospital.

So how is he a good guy? Or even why should he be considered redeemable? He even tells his roommates if they knew even a portion of what he's done over the years they would only see a monster and if he drinks blood from a human again he'll become the same thing.

Comment: Just retagged this to make it obvious that you're talking about the US version - at least I assume you are, because I've only seen the UK version and I don't recall most of that. :)

Comment: Yes it is the US version. The vampire is actually named Aidan as opposed to the UK where the actor is Aidan whereas his character is Mitchell. I didn't know there were two separate tags but that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I just created one, because I kept getting confused and figured others may as well.  I'm somewhat embarrassed because I just realised I'd been thinking the UK vampire's name was "Aidan Mitchell" (watched the first season recently) and that they were just using his last name but it turns out I was confusing the actor's name and the character's name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is redeeming is that, like humans, Aidan tries very hard to be good and abstain from what he believes is evil, but, like humans, often relapses.

It is really a clever twist, and perfectly follows the show's name. Aidan is even more human than even he tries to be. It is in his principles and value-system, not his actual actions. Although he has a hard time abstaining from succumbing to his nature, he still maintains his value system, which in a way, actually makes him human, in certain respects.

Thus, Aidan really is "Being Human". It is important to remember not to judge people based on their actions entirely, because people are flawed and fail at being perfect. Aidan epitomizes this very important aspect of what it truly means to "Be Human". In fact, without our values, we as humans would merely be animals, succumbing to our primal nature, and that would make us no different than any other animal - or vampire.

Whereas other vampires and werewolves embrace their nature and cast off any sort of value system, Aidan (and Josh) defy their animal/vampire nature and embrace the only thing left human about them - their value system. In fact, the show inspires us to contemplate, that without our values we are nothing but an animal. Our freedom to choose to defy our nature (i.e. you want to kill someone for insulting you, but you of course abstain) is really what makes us Human. Otherwise the world would be chaos and society would be destroyed, and we would become nothing but animals.

The show inpires people to consider that our "humanity" is more than simply our species (homo-sapien), but something greater than our flesh and bones. It even takes it a step further to include a ghost, who has absolutely no flesh or bones, but still has a Will, a choice, a freedom to decide, and thus all of them can choose to "be human" even though their physical bodies are not any longer the species of homo-sapien.

Moreover, the show further inspires us to consider that humans have souls, and, unlike other vampire shows, movies, or books, that if even a vampire chooses to, they can retain their "soul", that is, the thing within that gives us the freedom to have a higher thinking, and a  belief-system and value-system. The show suggests that this higher entity within us, which lives on even after death (in the case of the vampire or ghost), is the true thing that makes us human, not merely the flesh or blood flowing through our veins or the urges which urge us to hurt, maim, sex, or destroy.

Comment: wow I wasn't expecting to be so profound. lol

Comment: I could see this a lot more with the UK version with Mitchell but I didn't really see it with Aidan until last night's episode. Definitely saw it with Josh and even Sally but Aidan they've shown as a backslider too much. I think he's really having to cast off the perceived (or maybe real) requirements he has to his vampire community.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same feeling with the question. I only see how Aiden sinking in the recent episode. The plot is getting confused and not completed as the previous one. Josh still insists his "human"value and principle which lead to break up with Nora. Sally found the dark side of her mind, and she hesitates in the crossroad. But for Aiden, he fell in finding his feet in the new Vampire Union, losing his value and succumbing to purse in 10 episodes! His son Henry, his royal lover Suren, his boss Mother, his colleague Heggenman, even Bishop who revealing in his mind, all of these Vampires, he cannont fix any problems or maintain an appropriate relationship among them. I deeply feel that Aiden's charater is getting vague and boring in the season 2. Strongly impressed by intense and wet erotic scenes which acted by Aiden.